# Few object in one place

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one selector: #circle-timer and I have few objects which target is this selector. Is any options to display only the selected item?
Example:

```js
function timer(time){
  var target = $('.value');
 var counter = time;
  var id = setInterval(function() {
       counter--;
       if(counter < 0) {
             clearInterval(id);
       } else {
            target.text(counter);
       } 
  }, 1000);
}

var p = timer(60);
var c = timer(33)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer" id="round">
     <div id="circle-timer" class="circle-timer">
           <div class="time">
                   <p class="value">00</p>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
<ul>
 <li>show first timer</li>
 <li>show second timer</li>
</ul>
```

But is showing all in one time. I want show selected timer (**when click show first timer**), not all.

Comment: change it to a button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this  would help
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLkb32e1/)

```
$('li').click(function(){
  $(".value2").toggle();
  $(".value1").toggle();
})

function timer(time,element){
  var target = $('p.'+element);
    var counter = time;
  var id = setInterval(function() {
       counter--;
       if(counter < 0) {
             clearInterval(id);
       } else {
            target.text(counter);
       } 
  }, 1000);
}

var p = timer(60,'value1');
var c = timer(33,'value2')


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer" id="round">
     <div id="circle-timer" class="circle-timer">
           <div class="time">
                   <p class="value1">00</p>
                   <p class="value2" style='display:none'>00</p>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="value1">show second timer</li>
    <li class="value2" style='display:none'>show first timer</li>
</ul>
```